# Запись date() в mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Доброго времени суток!Проблема в следующем - пытаюсь вставить подготовленную дату в базу в поле типа datetime, запрос отрабатывает без ошибок, но значение в поле 0000-00-00.

```
$time=time()+7*60*60;
 $today = date("H:i:s",$time);
$query='INSERT INTO test SET time="'.$today.'"' ;
  if ($link->query($query) === TRUE) {
  echo "Время добавлено";
 } else {
  echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . $link->error;
}
```

Как правильно подготовить запрос, чтобы записать в поле дату из переменной ?

Comment: `но значение в поле 0000-00-00` - ты сам догадайся, могут ли  часы  иметь 4(!!!) цифры? 9999 часа? логично что ты тот тип поставил в БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
У вас тип поля стоит в `datetime` а там формат хранения времени следующий 

ГГГГ-мм-дд ЧЧ-мм-сс
```

Если залить в такой формат только вторую часть `$today = date("H:i:s",$time); //ЧЧ-мм-сс`,То первая часть `ГГГГ-мм-дд` будет заполнена нулями,в принципе и вторая часть тоже.Потому что время которое вы питайтесь залить будет пытаться добавится к первой части.

Решение:

```
//......
$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time);
//......
```

Comment: По условию надо хранить время и дату отдельно, но спасибо, я поменял тип полей на time и date   и значения стали сохранятся.

Comment: @Madushko Если послушаете мой совет то не будете так делать.Ведь всегда можно из этого формата узнать и `ГГГГ-мм-дд`  и `ЧЧ-мм-сс`.А вообще я храню всегда дату в секундах.Всегда проще работать с ним и выборка происходит быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Вы наверное неправильно указали структуры таблицы(тип поля). Если вам необходимо добавлять время, почему вы пишите только время без текущего дня?
Ставить дату корректнее средствами самого MySql.

```
alter table tbl_name add created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Попробуйте поле таким образом добавить и посмотрите как работает стандартными способами. Добавляйте запись, делая это поле Null, MySql сам выставит значение.

Comment: Нет необходимости хранить дату, необходимо хранить только время.